# Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7450.6 Gb

Tags: r, matrix, vector, size

I want to apply an Hungarian Solver, which minimizes the correspondence between distances in a 1000000x100000 distance matrix.

I have two databases with 1000000 observations and 40 variables (columns).
Before making the Hungarian algorithm, I have to build the distance matrix.
Distance is a numerical measure that represents how far apart individuals are, that is, a metric used to measure the proximity or similarity between individuals. The objective is calculate the distance between each observation in one data frame versus each observation in the other data frame.
To make the distance matrix, I used the following code:

```
rm(list=ls())
set.seed(21)

#Matrix with random values
M1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0,1)), nrow = 1000000, ncol = 40))
M2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0,1)), nrow = 1000000, ncol = 40))

row1 <- nrow(M1) #number of lines M1
row2 <- nrow(M2) #number of lines M2
col1 <- ncol(M2) #number of columns (which is the same in M1 and M2)
distances <- matrix(data = 0, nrow = row1, ncol = row2)

for(i in 1:row1){
  print("This is row")
  print(i)
  for (j in 1:row1){
    print("This is row")
    print(j)
    for (a in 1:col1){
      print("This is col")
      print(a)
      sum <- abs(M1[[i,a]]-M2[[j,a]])
      distances[[i,j]] <- sum
    }
  }
}


#Hungarian Solver
library(RcppHungarian)
library(ggplot2)

typeof(distances)
mode(distances) <- "integer"

typeof(distances)
distances <- as.matrix(distances)
HS <- as.data.frame(HungarianSolver(distances))
```

However, it gives error in the loop that creates a distance matrix: **"Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7450.6 Gb"**
Is there another way to do this? How can I reduce the computational level?

Thank you.

Comment: I strongly suspect this is just an intractably large problem. This is exactly what you get when you compute `1e6*1e6*8/2^30` (it takes 8 bytes to store a double-precision floating point value, 2^30 is the size of a gigabyte). Even if you could store the result, you've just set up a nested for loop that involves 4e13 operations ... adding 1+1 takes about 50 nanoseconds  on my computer, so your loop would take at *least* 2 million seconds (= 23 days) to compute ...

Comment: Check this website: https://rpubs.com/msundar/large_data_analysis

Comment: Thank you, I will research better the options that appear on the website you indicated.